# How can i refactor python numpy code?

Tags: python, numpy

```
def arr_func(arr,selected_pixels_list): 

        rows = 2 
        m = 0 
        n = 0 
        i =0

        #Calculate the number of pixels selected 
        length_of_the_list = len(selected_pixels_list) 
        length_of_the_list = int(length_of_the_list/4)*4 
        cols = int(length_of_the_list/2) 
        result_arr = np.zeros((rows,cols)) 

        while(i<length_of_the_list): 
            result_arr[m,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i]] 
            result_arr[m,n+1] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+1]] 
            result_arr[m+1,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+2]] 
            result_arr[m+1,n+1] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+3]] 

            i = i+4 
            m = 0 
            n = n+2 

        return result_arr 

import numpy as np

selected_pixel_data = np.load("coordinates.npy")
arr_data = np.load("arr.npy") 
response = arr_func(arr_data, selected_pixel_data)
print(response)
```

I try using "for loop" but it is not refractory.

```
for i in range(0,len(selected_pixels_list),4):
    n=i//2
    result_arr[m,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i]] 
    result_arr[m,n+1] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+1]] 
    result_arr[m+1,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+2]] 
    result_arr[m+1,n+1] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+3]]
```

---

```
For selected_pixel_data:
shape = (597616, 2)
dtype = int32

For arr_data:
shape = (1064, 590)
dtype = float64
```

Here arr_data is an array of data and selected_pixel_data is coordinates.
The function arr_func is used to create a new array with selected coordinates.
Is there any way to use the code more efficiently?

Comment: Can you show us sample data from both of your `.npy` files?

Comment: What does the code do? The title should state the purpose of the application. Thanks.

Comment: Setting `m = 0` over and again looks uncalled for.

Comment: (`refractory` as in *heat/fire-proof*, *robust/resilient*?)

Comment: arbitrarily assign height as half of the length is a very bad idea; One argument is numpy.array but the other is a nested list, this is a bad practice, both should be arrays then you can get the resolution of the second argument by simply calling its shape attribute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add PEP484 type hints.

`int(length/4)*4` can just use floor division, as in `length//4*4`.

Use `np.empty` instead of `np.zeros`.

Don't surround `(i<length_of_the_list)` in parens.

The first layer of simplification is identifying the repeating patterns in your indices and rewriting your loop such that it does index math and only one inner assignment:

```
def arr_func_sequential(arr: np.ndarray, selected_pixels: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    n_selected = len(selected_pixels) // 4 * 4
    result_arr = np.empty((2, n_selected // 2))

    for i in range(0, n_selected, 4):
        n = i // 2
        for d in range(4):
            j, k = selected_pixels[i + d]
            result_arr[d // 2, n + d % 2] = arr[j, k]

    return result_arr
```

But this is not nearly enough. You should do vectorised indexing. For your stated shapes, this should be equivalent:

```
def arr_func_vectorised(arr: np.ndarray, selected_pixels: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    flat = arr[selected_pixels[:, 0], selected_pixels[:, 1]]
    return flat.reshape((-1, 2, 2)).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape((2, -1))
```

Including basic regression tests, this looks like

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng


def arr_func_sequential(arr: np.ndarray, selected_pixels: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    n_selected = len(selected_pixels) // 4 * 4
    result_arr = np.empty((2, n_selected // 2))

    for i in range(0, n_selected, 4):
        n = i // 2
        for d in range(4):
            j, k = selected_pixels[i + d]
            result_arr[d // 2, n + d % 2] = arr[j, k]

    return result_arr


def arr_func_vectorised(arr: np.ndarray, selected_pixels: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    flat = arr[selected_pixels[:, 0], selected_pixels[:, 1]]
    return flat.reshape((-1, 2, 2)).swapaxes(0, 1).reshape((2, -1))


def test() -> None:
    rand = default_rng(seed=0)
    arr_size = 1_064, 590
    arr_data = rand.random(size=arr_size, dtype=np.float64)
    selected_pixel_data = rand.integers(arr_size, size=(597_616, 2), dtype=np.int32)

    for method in (arr_func_sequential, arr_func_vectorised):
        response = method(arr_data, selected_pixel_data)

        assert response.shape == (2, 298_808)
        assert np.isclose(6.867644672947648e-07, response.min())
        assert np.isclose(0.9999967667212489, response.max())
        assert np.isclose(0.4996104177145426, response.mean())
        assert np.allclose(response[:, 0], np.array((0.12815171, 0.05691355)))
        assert np.allclose(response[:, -1], np.array((0.27512743, 0.60253044)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```